# Azure CLI WAF Policy Rules in AzureCLI@2 task - Multiple IP Address

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I keep trying to run a script in a AzureCLI@2 task like so and it works if ipAddresses  is set to a single IP address, but not multiple:

```
        az network front-door waf-policy rule match-condition add \
          --match-variable "SocketAddr" \
          --operator "IPMatch" \
          --values "${{ parameters.stageConfig.ipAddresses }}" \
          --negate "true" \
          --name "DigitalTimecardsAllowedIPs" \
          --resource-group "${{ parameters.stageConfig.resourceGroup }}" \
          --policy-name "${{ parameters.stageConfig.policyName }}"
```

This works

```
  - name: ipAddresses
    displayName: IP Addresses
    type: string
    default: "167.60.67.178"
```

For multiple I have tried

```
    "192.168.1.1,10.10.1.1"
    "192.168.1.1/24,10.10.1.1/24"
    "192.168.1.1" "10.10.1.1"
    "192.168.1.1","10.10.1.1"
    "[192.168.1.1,10.10.1.1]"
```

etc. and nothing seems to work for adding multiple IP addresses.  This is going to be half a dozen valid IPs, those above are just examples.

I get the error for example
Message: WebApplicationFirewallPolicy validation failed. More information "Value 167.60.67.178,20.7.207.27 is not a valid IP Address in rule AllowedIPs".

The documentation just has

```
az network front-door waf-policy rule match-condition add \
    --match-variable SocketAddr \
    --operator IPMatch \
    --values "ip-address-range-1" "ip-address-range-2" \
    --negate true \
    --name IPAllowListRule \
      --resource-group <resource-group-name> \
      --policy-name IPAllowPolicyExampleCLI
```

What format do I need to put it in to allow multiple IP addresses?

Comment: Try adding the values in this format -values "ip-address-range-1" "ip-address-range-2" refer the complete command here - az network front-door waf-policy rule match-condition add \
--match-variable SocketAddr \
--operator IPMatch \
--values "ip-address-range-1" "ip-address-range-2" \
--negate true \
--name IPAllowListRule \
  --resource-group <resource-group-name> \
  --policy-name IPAllowPolicyExampleCLI

Comment: In your scenario - -values "192.168.1.1" "10.10.1.1"

Comment: I've tried that and it did not work, it's in the examples I posted, 3rd one down.

Comment: I tried again just in case:
Message: WebApplicationFirewallPolicy validation failed. More information "Value "167.60.67.178" "20.7.207.27" is not a valid IP Address in rule AllowedIPs".

Comment: I figured it out, that whole thing was wrapped in quotes, so it was really ""167.60.67.178" "20.7.207.27"" but the console didn't output that, I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom WAF policy for front door with the commands below:-

***Created front door WAF rule match condition with the command below:-***

**In Azure CLI:-**

> I have used the below command from this link - [Configure IP
> restriction WAF rule for Azure Front Door | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction)
>
> ```bash
>     --match-variable SocketAddr \
>     --operator IPMatch \
>     --values "192.168.1.1/24" "10.10.1.1/24" \
>     --negate true \
>     --name IPAllowListRule \
>       --resource-group siliconrg \
>       --policy-name IPAllowPolicyExampleCLI
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

I ran the below ***YAML script to add multiple IP's in the rule match condition for WAF front door*** :-

> ````yaml
> - main
>
> pool:
>
> vmImage: ubuntu-latest
>
>   
>
> steps:
>
> - task: AzureCLI@2
>
> inputs:
>
> azureSubscription: 'subscription(<subscription-id>)'
>
> scriptType: 'bash'
>
> scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
>
> inlineScript: |
>
> az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
>
> az network front-door waf-policy rule match-condition add \
>
> --match-variable SocketAddr \
>
> --operator IPMatch \
>
> --values "167.60.67.178/24" "20.7.207.27/24" "192.168.1.1/24" "10.0.0.1/24" \
>
> --negate true \
>
> --name IPAllowListRule \
>
> --resource-group siliconrg \
>
> --policy-name IPAllowPolicyExampleCLI ```
> ````

> I have used above CLI task command from this link here - [Configure IP
> restriction WAF rule for Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction)

**Output:-**

[image]

***Custom rule added in Portal like below:-***

[image]

[image]